# Get event of fotorama video play button being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento2, fotorama

I want to obtain the event during which this video player button is clicked

[image]

I want to observe when and how many the amount of it being clicked

I try to use the below code

```
require(['jquery'], function($){

    $('fotorama__stage__frame.fotorama-video-container.magnify-wheel-loaded.fotorama_vertical_ratio.fotorama__loaded.fotorama__loaded--img.video-unplayed.fotorama__fade-rear.fotorama__active').click(function(){
        alert('A');
    })

})
```

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
    
    $('div.product-video').click(function(){
        alert('A');
    })

})
```

but neither are working

I also tried doing as below to get the details upon on fotoroma:showend but unable to find any action triggered during the button is clicked

```
 .on('fotorama:fullscreenenter fotorama:showend', function (e, fotorama) {


      if(fotorama.activeFrame.$stageFrame){

          $('div.product-video').click(function(){
                  alert('A');
          })

      }
            
})
```

Not sure how do I obtain this click event. Anyone can help give suggestion?

Any help is kindly appreciated

Comment: nevermind, I am able to resolve this by using below

Comment: require(['jquery'], function($){

    $(document).on('click', '.fotorama__stage__shaft', function () {
        console.log(this);
    });

})

Comment: As you found your solution I'd suggest answering it yourself so that it can help others in the future, or deleting it, if you feel the solution is of no benefit to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Able to get the clickable element for this by using

```
require(['jquery'], function($){ 

$(document).on('click', '.fotorama__stage__shaft', function () { 
    console.log(this); 
}); 

})
```

Putting this here for reference if someone were to encounter this same issue in magento 2